# JAXBContext in javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext not throwing an exception

Tags: java, javax, xml-binding

JAXBContext in javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext is neither creating an instance of the package nor it is throwing an exception. The flow of the applicaton is fine until it comes to the below line in the code:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.test.package");
```

after that i dont see any exception even if the code is in try catch block nor the flow is not moving furthur as i dont see any logs after that. I am not sure what is causing this issue.

Comment: is jc null? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yes. @qtips I have tried to print he jc value but its not even printing the value. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant debugging with a debugger. Alternatively, have you tried printing just before and after the jc = ...? Is the print line not reached?

Comment: Yes just before jc i have kept a log statement which is printing fine. @qtips.

And sorry to say that i cant debug my application locally in eclipse by keeping breakpoints as there are lot of dependencies.